# File not found error when building XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, protocol-buffers, objective-c++, xctest

I am trying to write an XCTest Unit Test for my iOS application.  I am using XCode 5.1.1.

The issue I am having is when I include a header file which has an include that looks like this 
`#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>` it complains that it cannot find the file.

I have included the relevant path to the directory which contains the `google` folder in my Header Search Paths for my Test target.  I have marked it to always use the search paths and to search recursively.

My app target finds that path without any issues and I am including it the exact same way.  My Unit Test class is an Objective-C++ class, as I have changed the filename to a `.mm` extension.

Any ideas why I am hitting the file not found issue?

Comment: google framework is available for test project? If not make it available

Comment: I figured out what it was, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my search path was wrong.  I was giving the path from my test directory, but apparently the path Xcode wanted was from my project root (i.e. where my .xcodeproj file was)

Comment: Such as `$(PROJECT_DIR)/dir_to_header`, do NOT use absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

I, too, suffered from XCtests refusing to build because headers could not be found. As DawnSong suggests, $(PROJECT_DIR) is the way to go. Select the XCTest target, go to build settings and find the 'Header Search Paths' setting.
If your project looks like this:

```
MyProject
    MyProject.xcodeproj
    FolderA
       FolderA1
       FolderA2
    FolderB
```

Add the following paths (in the build settings of the **test target**):

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/FolderA               recursive
$(PROJECT_DIR)/FolderB               non-recursive
```